# How would I make this regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match the "e" in these strings:

> e
>
> e-x-ex
>
> e-x
>
> e-ex

However, I do not want to match the "ex" or dashes in any of them.

What I want in the regex is that it must match only the e in all of the above strings but not these:

> x
>
> x-ex
>
> ex

This is probably really easy, but I am not that accomplished at regex making.

I tried `e[^x]` but that didn't match the string "e" and matched "e-" in "e-x-ex"," "e-x", and "e-ex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
(?i)\be\b
```

**Explanation**

```
"
(?i)    # Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
\b      # Assert position at a word boundary
e       # Match the character “e” literally
\b      # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```